# java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(...) must not be null while trying to inflate using DataBindingUtil

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a BaseFragment class:

```
abstract class BaseFragment: Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var mBinding: ViewDataBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater, getLayoutId() , container, false)

        return mBinding.root
    }

    abstract fun getLayoutId(): Int

    abstract fun afterOnViewCreated()


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        afterOnViewCreated()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) { }

    fun getViewDataBinding(): ViewDataBinding {
        return mBinding
    }

    fun setClickListener(vararg views: View) {
        views.forEach { view -> view.setOnClickListener(this) }
    }

}
```

Which i extend to create new fragments like this:

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_home
    }

    override fun afterOnViewCreated() {
        activity?.let{
            homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        }
        //TODO:
    }

}
```

But, im getting this crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mu.chatonymous, PID: 23328
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBindingUtil.inflate<…nt_home, container, false) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBindingUtil.inflate<…nt_home, container, false) must not be null
        at com.mu.chatonymous.ui.base.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:21)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2612)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2087)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1861)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1817)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1717)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2650)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2639)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:897)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1228)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2646)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:176)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1340)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3281)
```

heres my app level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mu.chatonymous"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}


//androidx
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    //for selection single or multiple items in recycler view
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.0.0'


}
//test
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
//google
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
}
//3rd party
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What am i doing wrong? i know i can use LayoutInflater.inflate instead of DatabindingUtil.inflate, but ive used this flow without problems before. And i kind off need the viewDataBinding object for later use like i did here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, so i found the issue. Turns out even if u configured almost every setting properly you might forget/miss out on this little info. So, i'll share what i learnt here.

**Data binding layout files are slightly different and start with a root tag of `<layout>` followed by a data element and a view root element.** As mentioned in detail here: [Official Databinding Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)

So wrapping all your layouts with `<layout></layout>` will remedy this exception.

**e.g:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       ....

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you must wrap your xml in

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    tools:context=".ui.weather.WeatherFragment">

        ....../>
</layout>
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly on my device.
Are you sure that your layout is correct? Check it using `layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false)` in onCreateView. If there will be exception than DataBinding can't inflate your layout.

Comment: layoutInflater.inflate() works perfectly, so probably not an issue on my layout :'

Comment: And note, that in your code afterOnViewCreated() will be called before child's onViewCreated

Comment: i dont think so. Can u explain what u mean? because, afterOnViewCreated() is being called inside onViewCreated() of BaseFragment

Comment: First check layout tag is there or not as mentioned above but if its available then you can try "clean project" and "rebuild project" it might work.

Answer (score 0):

If the suggested solutions doesn't work for you, check if you have another xml file with the same name in the project.
At the end of the compilation, all xml files are merged.